# Fetching an image preview/snapshot from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a site where users can showcase their websites, i want an image preview/snapshot of their main page displayed after they submit a url, what is the easiest way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ruby gem https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer that generates thumbnail images from a given URL